# Karaf https SSL Not Working in Chrome getting ssl_server_cert_untrusted_issuer

Tags: google-chrome, karaf

I am trying to follow the following link

http://blog.nanthrax.net/2012/12/how-to-enable-https-certificate-client-auth-with-karaf/

I am able to access the Webconsole with SSL in IE 
[image]

But it is not working in Chrome I am getting and Certificate error. 
[image]

why it is not working in chrome ? I am getting ssl_server_cert_untrusted_issuer

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate is not signed by a trusted issuer. See here for the difference. 
[signed vs self signed certificates](https://www.thoughtco.com/signed-vs-self-signed-certificates-3469534)

Also, if you watch your screenshot of the IE closely, you can see that there is also a certificate error. Chrome is per default more restrictive than IE.

If you want to view the page in chrome, you can do this by adjusting chromes settings or install your certificate.

Comment: I am using mkdir -p etc/keystores
cd etc/keystores
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -alias serverkey -keypass password -storepass password -keystore keystore.jks
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -alias clientkey -keypass password -storepass password -keystore client.jks

Comment: Have you tried to install your certificate
[getting chrome to accept self signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)?

Comment: Yes I added the client certificate to the trust store in the chrome